# python app in WM-Menu

Tags: python, menu, gnome

BI wrote a python app for controlling one of my network devices. Now in want to add it to the Gnome Menu (Applications).

How can I create a new overall section like "My Apps" and then an entry for my app?

I've now created the files specified in the tutorial, but there's no menu entry at all.

here are my files:

**/usr/share/blafoo/applications/bla-foo.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application

Exec=genucard
Icon=bla-foo.ico

Name=Bla Foo App
Name[de]=Bla Foo App

Comment=Easy control of youre blafoo
Comment[de]=Einfache Steuerung Ihres blafoos
```

**/usr/shar/blafoo/desktop-directories/bla-foo.directory**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8

Icon=happyhacking.ico
Name=Happy Hacking
```

**/etc/xdg/menus/applications-merged/bla-foo.menu**

```
<!DOCTYPE Menu PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD Menu 1.0//EN"
<"http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/menu-spec/menu-1.0.dtd">
<Menu>
  <Name>Applications</Name>
  <Menu>
    <Name>Happy Hacking</Name>
    <Directory>bla-foo.directory</Directory>
    <Include>
      <Filename>bla-foo.desktop</Filename>
    </Include>
  </Menu>
</Menu>
```

Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: I am pretty sure you need to place the items in `/usr/share/applications` without the blafoo directory.

Comment: oh yeah... in this moment i understood, that it wasnt mentioned /usr/share/app/applications but /usr/share/applications.. Thats working now.. but another question: Where do i have to store the icon which is tergeted e.g. by Icon=BlaFoo ?

Comment: `/usr/share/icons` I think or `/usr/share/pixmaps` or in your application directory which could be something like `/usr/local/blafoos/` on Ubuntu but it is whatever you design it to be. You can give the full path on the `Icon=` setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this thing called the desktop specification, you can find more info about it here:

http://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/
http://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en

These files usually reside in `/usr/share/applications`

Comment: ive added my file according to the second link.. but its not working yet

Comment: I've restarted my laptop.. is this enaugh?

Comment: Should be. But you can try it anyway.